# Nested Form Not Showing Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, registration

I'm using devise for registration and am trying to nest a form for sign up and only that section doesn't appear in the form

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :languages_users
  has_many :languages, :through => :languages_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :languages_users
end
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
 def new
   build_resource({})
   resource.languages_users.build  
  respond_with self.resource 
 end

def create
 super
end
protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u|
      u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :bio, :location, :last_name, :first_name, :nationality, :avatar, languages_users_attributes: [:language_id, :level]) }
    end
end
```

relevant part of sign_up form

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: "users/registration_path(resource_name)") do |f| %>
 <%= f.fields_for :languages_users do |lu| %>
    <br>
      <div class="fields"> 
      <%= lu.collection_select(:language_id, Language.order('language ASC').all, :id, :language) %><br>
      <%= lu.hidden_field :level, value: 1 %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

relevant routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :languages
  resources :languages_users
  devise_for :users
end
```

any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

should work as is, are you sure you're not :

- reloading your `resource` instance between the `registration#new` controller action method and the view
- calling `resource.languages` somewhere, which would trigger a sql query on your intermediary `language_users` relation and flush it

Rails may also be confused because your table name pattern `languages_users` is devoted to define an intermediary table within a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) relation, try to rename your model or use this last relation type if it better fits your needs

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by reloading resource between the registration#new controller and the view? I haven't changed anything on devise except what I  put above - am I missing another step?   As well, languages_users is a join table between a language and user model, thus the name.

Comment: 1) in your layout view template maybe
2) if you don't have any logic into your language_user model you may wana use an has_and_belong_to_many relation between user and language, if you do intend to put some more stuff into this model (like a language fluency level) i would rename it.

Comment: I put the view above, so I do not think so.

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: "users/registration_path(resource_name)") do |f| %>
 <% resource.languages_users.each do |languages_user| %>
   <%= f.fields_for languages_user do |lu| %>
    <br>
      <div class="fields"> 
      <%= lu.collection_select(:language_id, Language.order('language ASC').all, :id, :language) %><br>
      <%= lu.hidden_field :level, value: 1 %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I get an `Unpermitted parameter: languages_user` when I make this update. I also notice that if there are errors on the signup form when submitted, the nested form disappears